# Why the repeat function does not seem to work?

Tags: command-line, bash

```
#function repeat   
repeat()  
{  
shift  
let b="$@"  
for i in {1..b} ; do echo Date starting `date` ; echo Before waiting `date`; sleep 6 ; echo Done waiting `date` ; "$@" ; done  
}
```

The first time i tried to use this function it worked superbly, then in the past few days it worked 2 times then its working only once now

```
$ repeat 7 ls
```

the output used to show 7 times earlier, then it showed it only twice, now its showing the output only once.
Please let me know what mistake is there in the script which has never been changed from the first day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify for what shell is the script intended. I will assume it's Bash.

Your function `repeat` is defined as (copied here from your post):

```
repeat()
{
shift
let b="$@"
for i in {1..b} ; do echo Date starting date ; echo Before waiting date; sleep 6 ; echo Done waiting date ; "$@" ; done
}
```

You are calling it with `repeat 7 ls`. So `$1` is `7` and `$2` is `ls`. The function executes:

```
shift
```

This throws away `$1`, `$1` becomes `ls`, `$2` is unset and `$#` is 1.

```
let b="$@"
```

`b` is set to `ls`.

```
for i in {1..b} ; do
```

The loop will be executed once with `i` set to `{1..b}`. (It looks like you wanted to try to generate some numbers using brace expansion; maybe `{1..6}` which looks quite similar?)

```
echo Date starting date
echo Before waiting date
sleep 6
echo Done waiting date ;
```

Display `Date starting date`, `Before waiting date`, wait 6 seconds, and finally display `Done waiting date`. Maybe you wanted `` `date` `` instead?

```
"$@"
```

`$1` is `ls` and `$#` is 1; this executes `ls`.

```
done
```

End of the `for` loop.

In general, the function will display a message, wait 6 seconds, display another message, then execute a command whose name is `$2`, possibly passing `$3`, ... as arguments to the command. `$1` is not used.

(I won't comment on the affirmation that in the past this function used to do something else.)

A working function definition would be:

```
repeat()
{
  local n i
  n="$1"
  shift
  for ((i = 1; i <= "$n"; ++i)); do
    echo
    "$@"
  done
}
```

For example:

```
$ repeat 3 ls -F

Calibre/  Documents/  Music/     Public/  Temp/       Videos/
Desktop/  Downloads/  Pictures/  System/  Templates/  examples.desktop

Calibre/  Documents/  Music/     Public/  Temp/       Videos/
Desktop/  Downloads/  Pictures/  System/  Templates/  examples.desktop

Calibre/  Documents/  Music/     Public/  Temp/       Videos/
Desktop/  Downloads/  Pictures/  System/  Templates/  examples.desktop
```

For production use some error checking may have to be added (there are at least two arguments, the first argument is a number, etc.).

Comment: can you please provide a script which will work properly ? date is typed as 'date' only

Comment: What should the function do?

Comment: repeat a command n number of times from terminal. It can be any command.

Comment: Edited the answer.